# Short story involving a robotic pilot in a futuristic war facing anti-robotic sentiment

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story during the late 1980s to early 1990s in an English language collection.

It's a standard "racism but dressed up" story of a squadron of pilots involved in a war against an enemy receiving a robotic pilot as a replacement for one of their recently deceased comrades.  The robot is a full humanoid robot, introduced to the squadron during their down time (probably in their mess hall or ready room), and replaces a human pilot directly.

The robot pilot is initially distrusted and disliked by the other pilots, excluding it from normal activities and friendships.

The squadron flew distinctive boomerang or banana shaped aircraft.

The story ends with a bombing attack on an enemy installation, and the sole bomb on target fails to go off.  The robot pilot is shot down over the target while trying to make it go off, and ejects.  The robot pilot eventually detonates the bomb by crawling over to it and banging on it to set it off (it may have just been its arm that crawls over to the bomb).

The pilots then readily accept the next replacement pilot - another robot.